# UIScrollView with a large number of UIButtons

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

What I want is a `UIView` with lots of `UIButtons` in it. They get placed and arranged according to data stored in an `NSArray`. Because there are quite a lot of buttons they don't fit on the screen all at once. The user should be able to zoom out to see all the buttons or to zoom in to see details (the label on them) and to easily select them.

I tried two different approaches:

1) I constructed a `UIView` subclass, put the buttons in it and an instance of this View inside a `UIScrollview`.

Effect: I can access all Buttons via their tag and scrolling and zooming works fine. BUT I can't get the buttons to handle any events (press on them)...

2) I wrote a `UIViewController` with exactly the same functionality and added an instance of it to the `UIScrollView`.

Effect: I can press the buttons now, but scrolling and zooming have stopped to work.

Here the relevant Code of the View:

```
    - (UIView *)initWithArray:(NSArray *)nArray{
self = [super init];
if (self) {        
    int count = [nArray count];
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]
                            initWithFrame:(__some Code to place the Button__);
        button.tag = i+1;
        NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:__code for generating Title__];
        [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self addSubview:button];
    }
}
return self;
```

}

And the Code for the matrixController:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
[super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *nArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] __some code___];
int count = [nArray count];
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]
                        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(__some Code to place the Button__];
    button.tag = i+1;
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:__code for generating Title__];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

}

And the code for the `ScrollViewController`:

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 970)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    //Zooming
    [scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.25];
    [scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:4.0];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];

    // constructing the view
    [scrollView addSubview:chartView];
    [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:chartView];
```

OR

```
    [scrollView addSubview:[matrixController view]];
```

How can I get this to work??

Comment: The scrollView is intercepting touch down events. Method 1) should have worked, you should select the touch up inside event for the buttons.

Comment: Even though the touch down event is not what he wants, it should still fire the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to get a scroll view containing multiple buttons to pan and zoom just fine, with the buttons still handling touch events:

```
- (void)didTapButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"Button %ld", (long)button.tag);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3.0f, scrollView.frame.size.height * 3.0f);
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0f;

    UIView *zoomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)];
    zoomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < 100; index++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake((scrollView.frame.size.width / 2.0f) - 50.0f, 10.0f + (50.0f * (CGFloat)index), 100.0f, 30.0f);
        button.tag = index;
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %ld", ((long)index + 1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [zoomView addSubview:button];
    }

    [scrollView addSubview:zoomView];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

EDIT: I said not to rely on tag in my comment below, yet I'm doing in here. :) It's merely so I could log the button number, so that part should be ignored.

Comment: Zooming and touching of the buttons seem to work fine, but how can I change one of their properties? They are inside a view inside a ScrollView inside a view. This: `[[[self.view viewWithTag:0] viewWithTag:0] viewWithTag:buttonTag]` can't possibly be the answer… Besides – it doesn't work…

Comment: You really shouldn't be relying on the `tag` property like this. It's not very flexible. Instead, you should hold on to your own collection of pointers to your objects of interest and index them similarly (such as in an array).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's been useful to me :) Just a question: it works fine in portrait mode, yet in landscape mode the scroll view is "cut" horizontally at the device's height (768px for iPad). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need to set the autoresizing masks for your scroll view. These determine how subviews are resized and positioned when their superview's frame changes. Look it up in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    UIButton  *scrollingbutton_outlet = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    scrollingbutton_outlet = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box_normal.png"];
    scrollingbutton_outlet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, img.size.width, img.size.height);
     [scrollingbutton_outlet setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    scrollingbutton_outlet.tag=i+1;
    [buttonArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1]];
    buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [scrollingbutton_outlet setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [scrollingbutton_outlet addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(scrollbuttonpress:)
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    scrollingbutton_outlet.frame = CGRectMake(img.size.width*i,0, img.size.width,      scrollviewoutlet.frame.size.height);
    [scrollviewoutlet addSubview:scrollingbutton_outlet];
    width = scrollingbutton_outlet.frame.size.width;
    height = scrollingbutton_outlet.frame.size.height;
    scrollviewoutlet.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width*i+scrollingbutton_outlet.bounds.size.width+5, height);
}
```